# Data simulation in R

Tags: r, simulation

Suppose I want to simulate 10 observations from lognormal distribution and repeat this 100 times. I wrote some R code, but for some reason it's not working. Here is the code:

```
for(i in 1:100) 
 {

x = rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)

 }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Worked fine for me.  Did you mean that the results of your 100 experiments are not being stored?  In your R code, x is an array of 10 observations, and the variable x is constantly being rewritten in every iteration of the loop, so at the end x only contains 10 observations.  Instead, try x = sapply(1:100, function(i) rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1))

Comment: Thanks, JCWong! I want to calcuate the mean and sd for each 10-observation. How this can be done? I tried mean(x), but it gave only the overall mean.

Comment: You have to create a matrix. Your code is replacing `x` in each iteration. To create this matrix use `x = t(replicate(100,rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)))`. To obtain the mean of each row use `rowMeans(x)`. The sd can be obtained using a loop for each row.

Comment: How about SDs and say skweness?

Comment: skewness and kurtosis are implemented in the R package `moments`. Have a look at this code `library(moments)
x = t(replicate(100,rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)))

means = rowMeans(x)
sds = sapply(1:100, function(i) sqrt(var(x[i,]))) 
sks = sapply(1:100, function(i) skewness(x[i,])) 
kurs = sapply(1:100, function(i) kurtosis(x[i,])) `.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code as well:

```
> x=matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=100)
> for(i in 1:100) 
+  {
+ 
+ x[,i] = rlnorm(10, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
+ 
+  }
> 
> apply(x,2,mean)
> apply(x,2,sd)
> library(moments)
> apply(x,2,skewness)
```

Comment: Or simply `x <- matrix(rlnorm(10*100,meanlog=0,sdlog=1), nrow=10)`